# record'ы ссылающиеся друг на друга

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, record

Возникла необходимость создать рекорды в PL/SQL Developer, которые ссылаются друг на друга. Во всем этом начал разбираться недавно, поэтому появились сомнения в достижении данной цели, но также в голове крутится мысль, что я не первый, кто задавался данным вопросом. Поэтому, если знаете как сделать или есть идеи реализации, то буду очень рад Вашей помощи, а пока продолжу гугление.

Пример:

```
TYPE rtype1 IS RECORD
(
/*some code*/
r_type2 rtype2;
);

TYPE rtype2 IS RECORD
(
/*some code*/
r_type1 rtype1;
);
```

Comment: Что-то не припомню, чтобы такое было можно. А как такая необходимость возникла?

Comment: Дело в том, что на основе xsd - схемы нужно сгенерировать рекорды и коллекции, а т.к. в xsd - схеме это не запрещено, такая необходимость возникла

Comment: В 11-м оракле есть тип XMLTYPE и пакеты для работы с xml. Я, правда, плотно с ними работал последний раз в 2011-м году ;) Но там точно можно было распарсить XML и работать со структурами данных для работы с XML. Попробуйте в эту сторону копнуть.

Comment: А, через xquery еще можно попробовать, хотя это уже совсем изврат будет.

Comment: что значит ссылаются друг на друга? это тип данных. при объявлении типа данных вы хотите использовать тип данных который еще не объявлен и для объявления которого требуется тип данных, который так же еще не объявлен...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После долгих поисков, решил задать вопрос на англоязычном stackoverflow и там предложили данное [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56653195/record-linking-to-each-other-in-pl-sql-developer), которое полностью соответствует моему требованию.